# Palo-Alto Interconnection

Tags: firewall, palo-alto

I am a novice with PaloAlto networks. For testing purposes, I have connected two PA-220 with each other. I configured the IP addresses from the same subnet. For me, like routers, these devices should have see each other. I also configured any any allow policy rule. But i cant see any logs on Monitor tab, even hit count is zero. Is there anythin that i should configure?

PA1

[image: PA1]

PA2

[image: PA2]

Rules on both sides

[image: Policy]

PA1 config

```
config {
  mgt-config {
    users {
      admin {
        phash $1$qgtctsss$IFjK8.WW68yNGYlZ9ROtV.;
        permissions {
          role-based {
            superuser yes;
          }
        }
      }
      Simral {
        permissions {
          role-based {
            superuser yes;
          }
        }
        phash $1$jheglxtv$bjWiIYdQ9p0hG5azX2hDu.;
      }
    }
  }
  shared {
    application;
    application-group;
    service;
    service-group;
    botnet {
      configuration {
        http {
          dynamic-dns {
            enabled yes;
            threshold 5;
          }
          malware-sites {
            enabled yes;
            threshold 5;
          }
          recent-domains {
            enabled yes;
            threshold 5;
          }
          ip-domains {
            enabled yes;
            threshold 10;
          }
          executables-from-unknown-sites {
            enabled yes;
            threshold 5;
          }
        }
        other-applications {
          irc yes;
        }
        unknown-applications {
          unknown-tcp {
            destinations-per-hour 10;
            sessions-per-hour 10;
            session-length {
              maximum-bytes 100;
              minimum-bytes 50;
            }
          }
          unknown-udp {
            destinations-per-hour 10;
            sessions-per-hour 10;
            session-length {
              maximum-bytes 100;
              minimum-bytes 50;
            }
          }
        }
      }
      report {
        topn 100;
        scheduled yes;
      }
    }
  }
  devices {
    localhost.localdomain {
      network {
        interface {
          ethernet {
            ethernet1/2 {
              aggregate-group ae1;
            }
            ethernet1/3 {
              aggregate-group ae1;
            }
            ethernet1/5 {
              layer3 {
                ipv6 {
                  neighbor-discovery {
                    router-advertisement {
                      enable no;
                    }
                  }
                }
                ndp-proxy {
                  enabled no;
                }
                ip {
                  192.168.20.10;
                }
                lldp {
                  enable no;
                }
              }
            }
            ethernet1/6 {
              layer3 {
                ipv6 {
                  neighbor-discovery {
                    router-advertisement {
                      enable no;
                    }
                  }
                }
                ndp-proxy {
                  enabled no;
                }
                ip {
                  192.168.30.30;
                }
                lldp {
                  enable no;
                }
              }
            }
          }
          loopback {
            units;
          }
          vlan {
            units;
          }
          tunnel {
            units;
          }
          aggregate-ethernet {
            ae1 {
              layer3 {
                ipv6 {
                  neighbor-discovery {
                    router-advertisement {
                      enable no;
                    }
                  }
                }
                lacp {
                  high-availability {
                    use-same-system-mac {
                      enable no;
                    }
                  }
                  transmission-rate slow;
                  enable yes;
                  mode active;
                }
                ndp-proxy {
                  enabled no;
                }
                ip {
                  192.168.10.11;
                }
                lldp {
                  enable no;
                }
              }
              comment Link_To_PA1;
            }
          }
        }
        vlan;
        virtual-wire;
        profiles {
          monitor-profile {
            default {
              interval 3;
              threshold 5;
              action wait-recover;
            }
          }
          interface-management-profile;
        }
        ike {
          crypto-profiles {
            ike-crypto-profiles {
              default {
                encryption [ aes-128-cbc 3des];
                hash sha1;
                dh-group group2;
                lifetime {
                  hours 8;
                }
              }
              Suite-B-GCM-128 {
                encryption aes-128-cbc;
                hash sha256;
                dh-group group19;
                lifetime {
                  hours 8;
                }
              }
              Suite-B-GCM-256 {
                encryption aes-256-cbc;
                hash sha384;
                dh-group group20;
                lifetime {
                  hours 8;
                }
              }
            }
            ipsec-crypto-profiles {
              default {
                esp {
                  encryption [ aes-128-cbc 3des];
                  authentication sha1;
                }
                dh-group group2;
                lifetime {
                  hours 1;
                }
              }
              Suite-B-GCM-128 {
                esp {
                  encryption aes-128-gcm;
                  authentication none;
                }
                dh-group group19;
                lifetime {
                  hours 1;
                }
              }
              Suite-B-GCM-256 {
                esp {
                  encryption aes-256-gcm;
                  authentication none;
                }
                dh-group group20;
                lifetime {
                  hours 1;
                }
              }
            }
            global-protect-app-crypto-profiles {
              default {
                encryption aes-128-cbc;
                authentication sha1;
              }
            }
          }
        }
        qos {
          profile {
            default {
              class {
                class1 {
                  priority real-time;
                }
                class2 {
                  priority high;
                }
                class3 {
                  priority high;
                }
                class4 {
                  priority medium;
                }
                class5 {
                  priority medium;
                }
                class6 {
                  priority low;
                }
                class7 {
                  priority low;
                }
                class8 {
                  priority low;
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
        virtual-router {
          default {
            protocol {
              bgp {
                enable no;
                dampening-profile {
                  default {
                    cutoff 1.25;
                    reuse 0.5;
                    max-hold-time 900;
                    decay-half-life-reachable 300;
                    decay-half-life-unreachable 900;
                    enable yes;
                  }
                }
              }
            }
            interface [ ae1 ethernet1/5 ethernet1/6];
          }
        }
      }
      deviceconfig {
        system {
          ip-address 192.168.1.1;
          netmask 255.255.255.0;
          update-server updates.paloaltonetworks.com;
          update-schedule {
            threats {
              recurring {
                weekly {
                  day-of-week wednesday;
                  at 01:02;
                  action download-only;
                }
              }
            }
          }
          timezone Asia/Baku;
          service {
            disable-telnet yes;
            disable-http yes;
          }
          hostname PA2;
          dns-setting {
            servers {
              primary 8.8.8.8;
              secondary 8.8.4.4;
            }
          }
          ntp-servers {
            primary-ntp-server {
              ntp-server-address time1.google.com;
              authentication-type {
                none;
              }
            }
          }
        }
        setting {
          config {
            rematch yes;
          }
          management {
            hostname-type-in-syslog FQDN;
          }
        }
      }
      vsys {
        vsys1 {
          application;
          application-group;
          zone {
            MGMT {
              network {
                layer3;
              }
            }
            Inside {
              network {
                layer3;
              }
            }
            Outside {
              network {
                layer3;
              }
            }
            DMZ {
              network {
                layer3;
              }
            }
            Interconnect {
              network {
                layer3 [ ae1 ethernet1/5 ethernet1/6];
              }
            }
          }
          service;
          service-group;
          schedule;
          rulebase {
            security {
              rules {
                Test {
                  to any;
                  from any;
                  source any;
                  destination any;
                  source-user any;
                  category any;
                  application any;
                  service application-default;
                  hip-profiles any;
                  action allow;
                }
              }
            }
          }
          import {
            network {
              interface [ ae1 ethernet1/5 ethernet1/6];
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

PA2 config

```
config {
  mgt-config {
    users {
      admin {
        phash $1$codxuhom$xXp//peldZrW.XwtJtgmn0;
        permissions {
          role-based {
            superuser yes;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    password-complexity {
      enabled yes;
      minimum-length 8;
    }
  }
  shared {
    application;
    application-group;
    service;
    service-group;
    botnet {
      configuration {
        http {
          dynamic-dns {
            enabled yes;
            threshold 5;
          }
          malware-sites {
            enabled yes;
            threshold 5;
          }
          recent-domains {
            enabled yes;
            threshold 5;
          }
          ip-domains {
            enabled yes;
            threshold 10;
          }
          executables-from-unknown-sites {
            enabled yes;
            threshold 5;
          }
        }
        other-applications {
          irc yes;
        }
        unknown-applications {
          unknown-tcp {
            destinations-per-hour 10;
            sessions-per-hour 10;
            session-length {
              maximum-bytes 100;
              minimum-bytes 50;
            }
          }
          unknown-udp {
            destinations-per-hour 10;
            sessions-per-hour 10;
            session-length {
              maximum-bytes 100;
              minimum-bytes 50;
            }
          }
        }
      }
      report {
        topn 100;
        scheduled yes;
      }
    }
  }
  devices {
    localhost.localdomain {
      network {
        interface {
          ethernet {
            ethernet1/2 {
              aggregate-group ae1;
            }
            ethernet1/3 {
              aggregate-group ae1;
            }
            ethernet1/5 {
              layer3 {
                ndp-proxy {
                  enabled no;
                }
                ip {
                  192.168.20.20;
                }
                lldp {
                  enable no;
                }
              }
            }
            ethernet1/6 {
              layer3 {
                ndp-proxy {
                  enabled no;
                }
                ip {
                  192.168.30.10;
                }
                lldp {
                  enable no;
                }
              }
            }
          }
          loopback {
            units;
          }
          vlan {
            units;
          }
          tunnel {
            units;
          }
          aggregate-ethernet {
            ae1 {
              layer3 {
                lacp {
                  high-availability {
                    use-same-system-mac {
                      enable no;
                    }
                  }
                  transmission-rate slow;
                  enable yes;
                  mode active;
                }
                ndp-proxy {
                  enabled no;
                }
                ip {
                  192.168.10.10;
                }
                lldp {
                  enable no;
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
        vlan;
        virtual-wire;
        profiles {
          monitor-profile {
            default {
              interval 3;
              threshold 5;
              action wait-recover;
            }
          }
        }
        ike {
          crypto-profiles {
            ike-crypto-profiles;
            ipsec-crypto-profiles;
            global-protect-app-crypto-profiles {
              default {
                encryption aes-128-cbc;
                authentication sha1;
              }
            }
          }
        }
        qos {
          profile {
            default {
              class-bandwidth-type {
                mbps {
                  class {
                    class1 {
                      priority real-time;
                    }
                    class2 {
                      priority high;
                    }
                    class3 {
                      priority high;
                    }
                    class4 {
                      priority medium;
                    }
                    class5 {
                      priority medium;
                    }
                    class6 {
                      priority low;
                    }
                    class7 {
                      priority low;
                    }
                    class8 {
                      priority low;
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
        virtual-router {
          default {
            protocol {
              bgp {
                enable no;
                dampening-profile {
                  default {
                    cutoff 1.25;
                    reuse 0.5;
                    max-hold-time 900;
                    decay-half-life-reachable 300;
                    decay-half-life-unreachable 900;
                    enable yes;
                  }
                }
              }
            }
            interface [ ae1 ethernet1/5 ethernet1/6];
          }
        }
      }
      deviceconfig {
        system {
          ip-address 192.168.1.1;
          netmask 255.255.255.0;
          update-server updates.paloaltonetworks.com;
          update-schedule {
            threats {
              recurring {
                weekly {
                  day-of-week wednesday;
                  at 01:02;
                  action download-only;
                }
              }
            }
          }
          timezone Asia/Baku;
          service {
            disable-telnet yes;
            disable-http yes;
          }
          hostname PA1;
          dns-setting {
            servers {
              primary 8.8.8.8;
              secondary 8.8.4.4;
            }
          }
          ntp-servers {
            primary-ntp-server {
              ntp-server-address time1.google.com;
              authentication-type {
                none;
              }
            }
          }
        }
        setting {
          config {
            rematch yes;
          }
          management {
            hostname-type-in-syslog FQDN;
          }
        }
      }
      vsys {
        vsys1 {
          application;
          application-group;
          zone {
            Outisde {
              network {
                layer3;
              }
            }
            Inside {
              network {
                layer3;
              }
            }
            DMZ {
              network {
                layer3;
              }
            }
            MGMT {
              network {
                layer3;
              }
            }
```

Comment: What traffic are you sending?

Comment: It is just for lab . I only want to make connectivity between two PA-220. Although, i allowed everything, i cannot ping from one another.

Comment: So you are trying to send ICMP. We really need to see the full configurations of both devices.

Comment: PA1- https://drive.google.com/open?id=13TZvCKeA8E8C6JR8Jys3S1ygr7zXn7za
PA2- https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xN5iN_hxYnh50IMlMt3m0qJwF4Hk5gA8

Comment: Simply copy and paste the text into the question, and use the Preformatted-text option (`{}`) on it.

Comment: Added configs to the question. Please, have a look

Comment: ethernet1/5 and 1/6 are aggregated, with the LAG using a different IP address - is that intentional? purpose? The subnet sizes/netmasks seem to be missing as well. Do you have any routes pointing across the link?

Comment: @Zac67 eth1/2 and eth/3 on both sides aggregated. There is no physical connection over those interfaces.
 
I thought that the problem could be related to lagg, so i tried connection over eht1/5 interfaces.

 1/5 and 1/6 are not aggregated at all.

Right now, the connection is over interfaces 1/5.  I haven't any configured route

Comment: Are you trying to ping PA2 from PA1, or are you trying to ping from a host connected to PA1, through PA1 to PA2?

Comment: @SimralAbdurahim I see - you should add the network masks and then pinging from one to the other PA should work. If it doesn't check the local ARP table. If it's populated it's a filtering problem (I'm not familiar with PA).

Comment: @Stuggi no, just pinging from PA1 to PA2

ping source 192.168.20.10 host 192.168.20.20

Comment: @Zac67 okay, I will try but, during configuration, it doesn't prompt to config network mask.
For me, both variants are applicable.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Comment: Palo Alto firewalls default to virtual wire mode meaning they are transparent to the existing network. This is the recommended mode of deployment. Unless you have a good reason to change the default behavior, don't.

Answer (score 2):

Dudes, thanks for your answers. Solved the problem. But I forgot to write here. I should have configured mgmt profile for pinging PA interface and besides that, I forgot to configure netmask.

Comment: Please accept your answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, lookin for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you able to the firewall traffic from the monitor page. the monitor page is dedicated to the traffic passing through the firewall. not generated from the firewall itself. 
https://knowledgebase.paloaltonetworks.com/KCSArticleDetail?id=kA10g000000ClU6CAK